# How to filter by property of embedded object in grails mongodb plugin

Tags: mongodb, grails, grails-orm

Grails 2.1.1, mongodb 1.0.0.GA.

I have two domain classes:

```
class Person {
  String firstName
  String lastName
  Address address
  static embedded = ['address']
}

class Address {
   String street
   String city
   String zip
}
```

I want to find all persons living in Redmond. I expect that something like:

```
Person.createCriteria().list() {
  eq 'address.city', 'Redmond'
}
```

would do the job but it does not. I know it is a 1st class citizen query for Mongo itself.

Is that not supported yet in mongodb 1.0.0.GA or I'm missing something obvious?
I'm confused mostly because embedded documents is a bread and butter for mongo and not supporting such an obvious use case renders the whole plugin unusable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i tested your example (copy-pasted your code) and it worked fine without any errors.

**Env**: Grails 2.0.4, mongodb 1.0.0.GA

Comment: My bad. It was a typo in my actual code I could only spot later. Thanks for you answer.